# Shift PrintScreen sometimes takes 10 tries or more

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, screenshot

Shift + Printscreen, trace a rectangle, nothing happens, no flash, no shutter-click
try again, Shift + Printscreen, trace a rectangle, nothing happens, no flash, no shutter-click
try again, Shift + Printscreen, trace a rectangle, nothing happens, no flash, no shutter-click
get frustrated, start rapidly Shift+Printscreening and drawing rectangles again and again until finally some portion of some screenshot is taken somehow.

Why couldn't this work the first time?  Why can't it work every time?  Is everyone else just taking full screenshots and editing them in GIMP or something to get the partial screenshot they wanted so this issue doesn't happen for them?

Comment: It works every time for me - occasionally I don’t get the shutter noise or flash, but the partial screenshot does save to pictures. It does sound frustrating - not sure how to go about investigating why it’s not working for you.

Comment: Works for me every time too .Would be good if you could show the options you tried in a table for clarity so we can test them again.

Comment: I didn't know there were options you could set for Shift+Printscreen. The only thing I can think of that I do differently from the average user, is that I have a drawing tablet attached instead of a mouse. It seems a bit redundant to have both. Other than that, it's more or less a vanilla install of ubuntu